# Fusesource - how to encode/decode base64 within a route

Tags: base64, fuseesb, jbossfuse, blueprint

Trying to encode/decode base64 within an XML document that is handled within a route in Fusesource ESB. 
We are using Blueprint.xml to try to encode/decode, but cannot find a way to do this.
We need our ruote to convert XML data to base64 string to hit an external webservice that requires some binary. We also need to extract some binary coming back from the webservice response and change this into .pdf (or a string first).

Answer (score 0):

Fuse ESB / Apache Camel offers a number of data formats for encoding/decoding
http://camel.apache.org/data-format.html

Though we don't have a Base64 out of the box. So I have logged a ticket to add such a format in a future release: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-5807

You can build a custom data format, or use the message translator EIP pattern with a Java bean and do a bit of java code to do the encoding/decoding yourself. http://camel.apache.org/message-translator.html

There is a camel-fop component for outputting to PDF: http://camel.apache.org/fop.html